# Endomorphism $Mat(2\times3,\Bbb R) \to Mat(2\times3,\Bbb R)$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Preparing for an exam, while studying old exams I came across this:

Let $ V = Mat(2 \times 3,\mathbb{R}) $ the $\mathbb{R}$-Vectorspace of real matrices of size $2 \times 3$. Let
$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
-3 & 1 \\
-25 & 7 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The Endomorphism $L_A: Mat(2 \times 3, K) \rightarrow Mat(2 \times 3, K)$ is given by
$L_A := A \cdot B$

Calculate the determinant, Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors of $L_A$

Hint: Left-multiplication with A affect the columns of B separately.

My issue: I don't understand how to get a square matrix from the $2 \times 3$ matrix. I asked an assistant, the only answer I got was that it's supposed to be a $6 \times 6$ matrix. I know how to solve the exercise ones I get the matrix, but I'm clueless.

Comment: A 2-by-2 times a 2-by-3 is another 2-by-3.  6-by-6 matrices will happen only once you start expressing things in a basis, which is what I guess the TA is getting at.

Comment: Do you know how to represent a linear map by a matrix ? If so, just write the matrix of $L_A$ (which is the application $B \mapsto AB$) w.r.t. the canonical basis of $\mathrm{Mat}(2 \times 3, \mathbb{K})$.

Comment: I agree with Randall. I think you need to consider your $2\times 3$ matrix as being multiplied on the left by your $2\times 2$ matrix.

Answer (score 3):

The roll-up-your-sleeves, explicit way is to find a basis for $M_{2\times 3}(\mathbb{R})$ and calculate the $6\times6$ matrix for $L_A$ defined by $L_A(X)=AX$.

The most obvious choice of six basis vectors is

$$ e_1=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \quad
e_2=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix},$$

$$ e_3=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \quad
e_4=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix},  $$

$$ e_5=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}, \quad
e_6=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix},  $$

What may not be obvious is why I paired them up this way. This is because $L_A$ acts on the three columns of $X\in M_{2\times 3}(\mathbb{R})$ independently. You will see the effect of this on the $6\times 6$ matrix $[L_A]$ when you finish working it out.

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}$ for full generality.

The first column of a matrix (with respect to a basis) can be read off the coefficients of the basis vectors we get by applying the linear transformation to the first basis vector. We calculate $L_Ae_1$:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} a & 0 & 0 \\ c & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, $$

or in other words $L_A(e_1)=ae_1+ce_2$. This tells us the first column of $[L_A]$:

$$ [L_A]=\begin{bmatrix}a & \ast & \ast & \ast & \ast & \ast \\
c & \ast & \ast & \ast & \ast & \ast \\
0 & \ast & \ast & \ast & \ast & \ast \\
0 & \ast & \ast & \ast & \ast & \ast \\
0 & \ast & \ast & \ast & \ast & \ast \\
0 & \ast & \ast & \ast & \ast & \ast \end{bmatrix} $$

(The $\ast$s are unknown at the moment.) That's the first column down. I'll let you find the other five columns. Note the determinant of a block-diagonal matrix is the product of the diagonal blocks' determinants.

Comment: Thank you so much, this helps a lot. Here's the matrix I got
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
c & d & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & a & b & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & c & d & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a & b \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & c & d \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Quick follow-up. How is the order of base-matrices given, as in, how do I know where the 1 is in any given base-matrix. For example why is this not correct:
$$
e_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: @josh You can pick whatever basis vectors you want; it's a matter of choice. I picked this one so the $6\times 6$ would come out block-diagonal, following the hint given in the problem. What you got is correct.

Comment: Perfect, that's what I figured, tested it with some variation :) Thanks very much!